# Correct image path CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs

The goal is to stylize all list elements with custom bullets

**My folder structure:**

```
-src
  |-assets
     |-images
        |-image.svg
     |-styles
        |-_base.scss
  |-index.js
```

**_base.scss:**

```
ul {
  li {
    background-image: url(../images/image.svg);
  }
}
```

**index.js:**

```
import './assets/styles/index.scss';
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
      ...
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Throws error:**

> **Failed to compile** 
>   ... 
>   Module not found: Can't resolve '../images/image.svg' in 
>   'path/to/project'

Not able to understand what is a problem with image path

Comment: This appears to be a Webpack configuration problem. Can you include your `webpack.config` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is your styles folder structure:

```
|-styles
  |-_base.scss
```

Where's your `index.scss` (inside which you should be importing `_base.scss`)?